C++ Compiler and Tools in Conda environment on Mac M1
Hi I am new to using Conda as a package manager and I am trying to install packages I need for a C++ development environment on Mac M1.
So far I have installed the packages named cmake, clangxx, and clang-format from conda-forge. I don't see a clangd package available (the language server). clangd is used by my text editor helix which I also installed in my conda environment. But right now clangd is still pointing to my system's Apple clangd
I do notice packages like libclang and clangdev but I am not sure what those do? Are those just for people that want to develop on clang and build it from source themselves with whatever compiler they already have on their system? Would clangd be in those (I know the brew package manager puts clangd in the llvm package along with the compilers and other tools)?
How can I get clangd into my conda environment? Is it available in some package named differently? Or is it something that I need to build myself? Any tips or pointers on that if I need to build it myself?

Does this answer your question? How to install c++ program into conda environment from source
